# /suggested-edits "Try it": Link for "suggested_edit_id" is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2

When using the "Try it" feature on [/suggested-edits](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/suggested-edits), the link for the  `suggested_edit_id` points towards stackexchange.com and not towards the respective site.

For example, retrieve data using the "Try it" feature for this query

> /2.0/suggested-edits?pagesize=1&todate=1337731200&order=desc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow

which results from the following parameters

- `todate` = 2-05-23
- `pagesize`= 1
- rest left to defaults

The link belonging the value for `suggested_edit_id`, which is `270139` points towards

> https://api.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/271572

Instead it should point to

> https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/271572

The current link just returnes the following message upon retrieval:

> {"error_id":404,"error_name":"no_method","error_message":"no method found with this name"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That bug in the test console has been fixed in the latest deploy.

We simply weren't making the links absolute for suggested edits, a silly oversight.